# Generating Functions - Extracting Coefficients

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, power-series, generating-functions

In many counting problems, we find an appropriate generating function which allows us to extract a given coefficient as our answer.

In cases where the generating function is not one that is easily used as an infinite sum, how does one alter the generating function for simpler coefficient extraction? The question I'm looking at involves the following generating function:

f(*x*) = ($x^3$ + $x^4$ + . . . + $x^8$)$^4$, and we seek the coefficient of $x^2$$^4$ in f(*x*). To start, we convert to a simpler form. With ($x^3$ + $x^4$ + . . . + $x^8$)$^4$ = $x^1$$^2$(1 + x + $x^2$ + . . . + $x^5$)$^4$ = $x^1$$^2$((1 - $x^6$)/(1 - x))$^4$, the answer is the coefficient of $x^1$$^2$ in (1 - $x^6$)$^4$(1 - x)$^-$$^4$

Why is this true? How does $x^1$$^2$ come about, allowing for the common (1 + x + $x^2$ + . . . ) sum ?

Comment: The answer is definitely *not* just the exponent of $x^{12}$ in $(1-x^6)^4$. You still need to include the division by $(1-x)^4$, which is multiplication by $(1+x+x^2+\cdots)^4$.

Comment: As to why it is the coefficient of $x^{12}$, that is because we already factored out an $x^{12}$ when we took out the common terms $(x^3)^4=x^{12}$.

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for the coefficient of $x^{24}$ in:$$x^{12}\left(\frac{1-x^6}{1-x}\right)^4$$

Which is the same as the coefficient of $x^{24-12}=x^{12}$ in $$\left(\frac{1-x^6}{1-x}\right)^4\tag{1}$$

Now, $$(1-x^6)^4 = 1-4x^6+6x^{12}-4x^{18}-x^{24}$$

And $$\frac{1}{(1-x)^4} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \binom{n+3}{3}x^n$$

So what is the coefficient of $x^{12}$ in the product? It is $$\binom{12+3}{3}\cdot 1 + \binom{6+3}{3}\cdot (-4) + \binom{3}{3}\cdot 6$$

More generally, the coefficient of $x^k$ in (1) is:

$$\binom{k+3}{3}\cdot 1 + \binom{k-3}{3}\cdot (-4) + \binom{k-9}{3}\cdot 6 +\binom{k-15}{3}\cdot (-4) + \binom{k-21}{3} \cdot 1$$

And yes, if $k>20$ this will evaluate as zero.